# How do I follow a specific user on Twitter at the click of a button?

Tags: php, twitter

I have tried:

```
        $id = "@puppies";
        $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        $toa->post('friendships/create', array('user_id' => $id));
```

and

```
        $id = "puppies";
        $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        $toa->post('friendships/create', array('user_id' => $id));
```

and

```
        $id = puppies;
        $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        $toa->post('friendships/create', array('user_id' => $id));
```

and

```
            $id = "puppies";
            $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            $toa->post('friendships/create', ['user_id' => $id]);
```

Right now I am using the  Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth library.

Comment: What happens when you try all of those things?

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
$object = $connection->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => 'puppies'));*emphasized text*
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!